# Php verification email with md5 hash and write to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, email

I have this form on my website.

```
<form id="contact-form" action="mail.php" method="POST">
                <input type="month" name="age" id="your-name" minlength="2" maxlength="2" placeholder="(your age here)" required><p>and</p>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="(your email address)" required>
              <p>
                <button type="submit">
                  <svg version="1.1" class="send-icn" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="36px" viewBox="0 0 100 36" enable-background="new 0 0 100 36" xml:space="preserve">
                    <path d="M100,0L100,0 M23.8,7.1L100,0L40.9,36l-4.7-7.5L22,34.8l-4-11L0,30.5L16.4,8.7l5.4,15L23,7L23.8,7.1z M16.8,20.4l-1.5-4.3
                l-5.1,6.7L16.8,20.4z M34.4,25.4l-8.1-13.1L25,29.6L34.4,25.4z M35.2,13.2l8.1,13.1L70,9.9L35.2,13.2z" />
                  </svg>
                  <small>Subscribe</small>
                </button>
              </p>
              <span class="href"><p>By clicking subscribe button your agree to our <a href="term.html" target="_blank">Terms of Use</a></p></span>
            </form>
```

and this mail.php file

```
    <?php

    $url = 'url';
    $fromEmail = 'support@site.com';

    $Hash = md5(rand(0,1000)); //random hash for verification email

    // Grab our POSTed form values
    // Note that whatever is enclosed by $_POST[""] matches the form input elements
    $Age = $_POST["age"];
    $Email = $_POST["email"]; 
    // Connect to our DB with mysql_connect(<server>, <username>, <password>)
    $sql_connection = mysql_connect("host", "databasename", "password");

    mysql_select_db("database", $sql_connection);

    // Probably should check to make sure the connection was successful
    // But I'm too lazy...
 $query="select * from table where email = '$Email'";
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $numOfRows=mysql_num_rows($result);
    if($numOfRows > 0)
    {
    echo 'email allready exist!';

    }
else
{   $sql = "INSERT INTO databasename (
                age,
                email,
                hash,
                date_1

            )
            VALUES (
                '". mysql_escape_string($age) ."', 
                '". mysql_escape_string($Email) ."',
                '". mysql_escape_string($Hash) ."',
                NOW()
            )";
    mysql_query($sql, $sql_connection);
    $to = $Email;
    $subject = 'Veryfi you sing up';
 $msg =   '

Thanks for signing up!
Your account has been created, you can login with the following credentials after you have activated your account by pressing the url below.


Please click this link to activate your account:
http://www.sait.com/verify.php?hash='.$Hash.'&email'.$Email.'

'; // Our message above including the link
    $headers = 'From:site.com' . "\r\n";

    mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

    mysql_close($sql_connection);
    echo 'Check your email for a link ...';
}
?>
```

Witch send link for verification on client email and write in the database email hash age date but I have a problem when I click the link for verification I can't figure it out how to do it for me everything seems to look like proper code but I am new in PHP and have many to learn.
And this is my 3rd PHP file verifie.php

```
$sql_connection = mysql_connect("host", "database", "pass");
mysql_select_db("databasename", $sql_connection);

$_GET['age'];
$_GET['email'];
$_GET['hash'];
$Active = 0;
//if(isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email']) AND isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash'])){
  if(isset($_GET['hash']) && !empty($_GET['hash']) AND isset($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['email'])){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO seconddatabase (
                age,
                email,
                ip,
                hash,
                date_1

            )
            VALUES (
                '". mysql_escape_string($Age) ."', 
                '". mysql_escape_string($Email) ."', 
                '". mysql_escape_string($Ip) ."',
                '". mysql_escape_string($Hash) ."',
                NOW()
            )");
        echo 'you email was verefied';}
else{echo 'We have a problem at the moment please try again later'}


?>
```

If someone can help me i will be happy.
p.s I know my code is Deprecated but for now I just want to figured out how to make it works that way.

Comment: At the end I get We have a problem at the moment please try again later.

Comment: In the link, `email'.$Email`.. you aren't building the parameters correctly. As a side note, I'd make the hash unique and wouldn't include the email address in the link. As a side note II, you're inserting in `seconddatabase` a bunch of values you don't have.

Comment: Be aware that the mysql_ extension was ***REMOVED*** from PHP version 7. You should now be using either the mysqli_ extension or PDO (in either case using prepared statements)

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: MD5 is a worthless hashing algorithm, it's been compromised, so you must use something like SHA2 at the minimum. Additionally, this only ever generates 1,000 different values, which is a really small search space. Try generating a random string instead, that's often much more secure.

Comment: Thank you for the answers.I will take notes from what all you suggest and will try harder.This is just a lazy scripts found online and is not up to date to the now  standards.

Comment: If you are using PHP5.* then isset($_GET) and empty($_GET) in both the same if statement might throw some warnings. In PHP7 there are some nifty operators like: ?: (also in PHP5) and ?? (not available in PHP5). 
You might write something like this: `$hash = $_GET['hash'] ?? false;` to fallback to `false` when hash is not available or is falsified.
Next you can check if `$hash !== false`. It's more reliable.

Comment: There's absolutely **NO POINT** using sha2 over  MD5 with such a low entropy secret. Using `md5(rand(1,10000) . time() . "s3cr3t");` would be massivley mode secure than `openssl_digest(rand(0,1000), 'sha256');`. A little learning is a dangerous think....(google the rest of the quote).